# test element in object is empty with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I have this code, and the npm run test give me a problem with the coverage.
I see the coverage html and i see that my deconstruction, url='' appear in yellow.

I see the problem and i can see this:

```
function Team(props) {
  const { team } = props;
  const {
    url = '', //this element appear in yellow, so is not being testing.
  } = team;
  const context = useAppContext();
  const { sportEvent, protocol } = getProperties(context);
  const { arcSite, outputType } = context;
  const basePath = getBasePath(context);
  const infoTeamPicture = translateMessage({ arcSite, id: 'infoCard.infoTeamPicture', defaultMessage: 'Escudo/Bandera equipo' });
  const initPath = getInitPath(team, protocol, basePath);
  return (
    outputType === 'amp' ?
      <TeamAmp infoTeamPicture={infoTeamPicture} team={team} initPath={initPath}/>
      :
      <figure className="ext ext-ic ext-ic--team">
        <div className="ext-ic__wr" {...getDTMRegion(ACTIVITY_MAP_NAME)}>
          <a href={`${initPath}${url}`} className="ext-ic__img">
            <img
              src={`${sportEvent.host}${team.image60}`}
              alt={infoTeamPicture}
              width="80"
              height="80"
            />
          </a>
            <div className="ext-ic__inf">
                <a href={`${initPath}${url}`} title={team.shortName} className="ext-ic__tl"><span>{team.shortName}</span></a>
                <InfoList team={team} />
            </div>
            <InfoButtons protocol={protocol} info={team} initPath={initPath}/>
        </div>
        {team.competition && <Competition competition={team.competition} />}
      </figure>
  );
}
```

I try to create a new test like:

```
it('no render url', () => {
    const specificTeams = {
      shortName: 'Real Madrid',
      country: 'España',
      url: '',
      urlTag: 'as.com/m/tag/real_madrid/a?omnil=src-app',
      image60: '/img/comunes/fotos/fichas/equipos/small/2x/1.png',
      image100: '/img/comunes/fotos/fichas/equipos/large/1.png',
      elementType: 'team',
      competition: {
        name: 'LaLiga Santander 2020/2021',
        normalized: 'primera',
        standing: [],
        nextGames: {},
      },
    };
    const instance = shallow(<Team team={specificTeams}/>);
    expect(specificTeams.url).toEqual('')
  });
```

but i can not achieve that the coverage arrive to 100%.
Someone can help me to understand how to test this kind of things?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use **JSON.stringify** for that, because it will return **'{}'** string. And unit test will be:

```js
expect(JSON.stringify(someObject)).toBe('{}');
```

Comment: I voted up your answer, but how did you test json object for a field which is empty or undefined? Actually jest offers special matches like ```toBeUndefined``` for this case https://jestjs.io/docs/using-matchers

Comment: If I understood you correctly you can do

```
expect(someObject.field).toBeUndefined;
```

Also if you do `JSON.stringify({field: undefined})` you will get `'{}'` which means that `expect(JSON.stringify(someObject)).toBe('{}');` will work.

Answer (score 0):

i did find a solutions that works.
In my case, i need to pass an empty object in my test, to check the empty object that is in the real code.

Just like that:

```
it('no render url', () => {
    const specificTeams = {          
      url: '', 
      },
    };
    const instance = shallow(<Team team={specificTeams}/>);
     expect(instance).toBeDefined();
  });
```

The other way to do this, would be just pass the object totally empty, but sometimes the test could send you an error. An undefined message about the object.